# docker http proxy connection timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, http, proxy

Have a simple java app calling external APIs via http proxy. application is dockerized and works perfectly fine across corporate proxy.
however it is unable to reach proxy in aws and gives connection timeout when it is run as aws fargate task. is there a way to troubleshoot fargate container?

```
`

    private void setProxySetting(EventPortType port) {
    try{
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
    HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
    http.getClient().setProxyServer("***host***");
    http.getClient().setProxyServerPort(80);
    http.getProxyAuthorization().setUserName("***username***");
    http.getProxyAuthorization().setPassword("***password***");
 }catch (Exception e) {
  logger.error("Please Enter your proxy setting in MyClass class", e);
 }
}
`
```

Comment: Do your tasks have internet access?

Comment: the vpc and subnet tied to the task are in the same sec group as ec2-proxy which is internet facing

Comment: For example, is the task set to have public IP?

Comment: no it is not having public ip

Comment: Shoudn't it have public ip? Maybe that's why it times out?

Comment: worked fine after admin edited the uri in tinyproxy